# JExcel -- Write a cell value that may be a number or empty

Tags: java, excel, jexcelapi

In JExcel, you can do:

```
new Number(column,row,value)
```

but null is not an accepted value.

For labels, using null as a value is fine.

Is there a way to create a cell that is either a Number or null, without doing this logic manually, as in:

```
if (value != null) {
  return new Number(column, row, value)
} else {
  return new Label(column, row, null)
}
```

Comment: I had same problem recently and solved it in the same way. There may be a better way but google and API just claimed that JExcel is old :/  I'd also be happy to get some better way to do that